# Measuring distance - Windows phone app

Tags: windows-phone-7

Good evening all.

I'm just trying to collate some ideas really and was wondering if I could pick some brains.

I'd like to develop an app that relies upon measuring distance reasonably accurately. So for example, I have a central point, I want to be able to detect whether the phone is within a radius of a meter.

How could I achieve this?

The points would be static but I don't think GPS would be accurate enough to rely on this solely.

I'm definitely not a hardware chap but is there a way of combining GPS and some other sort of transmitter to ensure accuracy?

Any help or suggests greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One meter accuracy?  It's probably not going to happen with any phone hardware out there - definitely not with any Windows Phone.  GPS isn't accurace enough without a differential beacon, and phones don't have the hardware to receive that (and I doubt you have a differential transmitter either).

Answer (score 1):

The location service on the phone (assuming high accuracy is selected) combines data from GPS, cell towers and WiFi hot spots to provide a location.

There is no way to include the use of other sensors to improve this data.

You also won't be able to get the level of accuracy you're after from the phone. It's just not designed for the purpose you describe.